# Why is it that after installing a reset button it displays "NaN" if I want to do new calculation?

Tags: javascript

I have set a reset button to clear a paragraph of a number obtained after a calculation and when I press it and want to restart a calculation again, it displays "NaN" instead of doing the calculation.

HTML

```
<!--input and paragraph-->
<input type="button" value="Total" class="qantP" onclick="decalcNumber()">
<p class="parafQ" id="numberProd">0</p>

<!--button of resetting-->
<input class="réinit" type="button" value="Remise à Zéro Simulateur" onclick="resetSimul()">
```

JavaScript

```
function resetSimul() {
    getNumberProd = document.getElementById("numberProd"),
    getNumberProd.textContent = "0";
}

function decalcNumber() {
    let volume1 = document.getElementById("quantEntrée1").value, 
    volume2 = document.getElementById("quantEntrée2").value, 
    inNumber = document.getElementById("numberProd");
    inNumber.textContent = parseInt(volume1) + parseInt(volume2) 
}
```

Comment: I provide my shortened function because it has 34 occurrences like:   parseInt(volume1) + parseInt(volume2)

Comment: That is already good. I am seeing that you are using two elements with the id quantEntree1 and 2 try not to use diacritics in entity ids or class names.

Comment: maybe because I use this to empty my form getAmount4.value =""  when I should be using this reset(), non?

Comment: but reset() it don't working for me. I'm an apprentice and it's my one function reset() LOL

Comment: I find it! It's because i have do getAmount.value = ""; and we must do getAmount.valueAsNumber = ""; Thank you to everybody!

Comment: Please mark your question as self answered in that case ;)

Comment: where does i must write this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this, however, I don't know what's in your decalcNumber() function.

```js
function resetSimul(){
getNumberProd = document.getElementById("numberProd");
getNumberProd.textContent = "0";
}

function decalcNumber(){
let volume1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantEntrée1").innerHTML); 
let volume2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantEntrée2").innerHTML); 
inNumber = document.getElementById("numberProd");
inNumber.textContent = volume1 + volume2 
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Total" class="qantP" onclick="decalcNumber()" 
>
<p class="parafQ" id="numberProd">0</p>
<p class="parafQ" id="quantEntrée1">2</p>
<p class="parafQ" id="quantEntrée2">3</p>

<input class="réinit" type="button" value="Remise à Zéro Simulateur" 
onclick="resetSimul()">
```

Comment: The question has been edited, you may want to consider updating your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I find it! It's because i have do getAmount.value = ""; and we must do getAmount.valueAsNumber = ""; Thank you to everybody!